# Virtualbox5.1 on Mac to KaliLinux VM, wont send files back and forth?

Tags: osx, kali-linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have set the settings to bidirectional:

```
Settings > Advanced > [both to BIdirectional]
```

but it seems that for some reason I still cant move files about.

I know that when I was using my windows machine I could literally just use vagrant and it would set up a communal spot for me to dump files.

I think when i used to use vmware, i also could move files, but i have no idea how to do this with Virtual box.

I have rebooted the vm as well after adjusting settings.  Is there something I am missing when it comes to allowing me to move files from Host to VM and back?  I have some configurables I want to work with, and a lot of it is too bulky to just transfer with github, pastebin, or other.

I am not sure if there is anything i could leverage within VBBOXADDITIONS, which looks like a mounted file containing *additions*.  I just dont know what *additions* means.

Comment: Have you installed guest additions? `apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11` then reboot. [Source](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest)

Comment: Ii did, and it says it is installed.  I rebooted then, and it still doesnt find any of the shared folders I set up in VirtualBox.  Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: Correction, It worked on my one machine.  Im testing it on my other one.  Thanks!   It seems like this is the way to get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must install **virtualbox guest additions** for this to work.

First:

```
apt-get update
```

Then:

```
apt-get install -y virtualbox-guest-x11
```

Finally:

```
reboot now
```

This should get everything working.

[Source](https://docs.kali.org/general-use/kali-linux-virtual-box-guest)